# How to calculate specific treasury bond yields

Tags: macroeconomics, bonds, yield

I am having trouble finding the correct answer to this question:

**Question**: What would the yield be on a 1.75 percent, $1,000, 10 year Treasury bond if the market price of the bond was 950 dollars?

I know that the formula for calculating the yield is: Annual interest payment/Price paid for the bond.

The annual interest I got was 0.0175 * 1000 = 17.5
The price paid for the bond is 950.

17.5/950 = 0.02.

However, this answer is correct. Could someone explain to me why and how to achieve the correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need YTM? https://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/yieldtomaturity.asp

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: What are the assumptions about the stream of coupon payments? In principle they would also need to be discounted. By the way, you forgot the yield on the principal, I think.